# Lithium PHP: Open view without layout

Tags: php, layout, view, fragment, lithium

I am using the PHP framework Lithium (aka li3). I want to be able to **open just a view** (ie without a layout) in a jquery dialog box. Ideally, I would like this to be done with a small modification to the URL, for example:

```
Normal path to action: http://localhost/controller/action/ 

View only path to action: http://localhost/controller/action/view_only/
```

This obviously still has to work with normal URL parameters and GET requests. Additionally, I would love not to have to change any existing controllers.

Does anybody know how I could achieve this?

Thanks,
Max.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// In the controller:

if ($someCondition) {
    $this->_render['layout'] = false;
}
// ...where $someCondition is based on whatever URL modification you do
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using the args parameter and setting up new routes to make that compatible with passing in an ID too.